# Make Dynamic ImageViews clickable

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, ibaction

I'm working on an app which dynamically pulls the images from the images folder and displays them in a ScrollView, very similar to [this tutorial code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Listings/MyViewController_m.html) from Apple (look at the viewDidLoad method):

Every image gets put into an ImageView. Now I want to make every picture clickable, but since it's dynamic I can't create a fixed amount of IBActions + it would be very repetitive and copy/paste, which I want to avoid.

So basically this code:

```
-(IBAction)Fork {
[buttonImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Fork.png"]];
}
```

but for every image that gets created. I'm especially confused because I can't 'connect' the IBActions to the button through the Storyboard.

I appreciate any help with code hints since I'm a beginner.

Comment: Add a tap gesture recognizer to your image view. On tap have a method called. Have the same method called. In your image view add a tag. When the method is called look for the tag and you are all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the click to be handled by a single action and pass the image view as the sender where you can differentiate your action accordingly.

You can use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to get started quickly:

```
UIImageView *imageView = ... // However you're creating it
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapper = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] init] autorelease];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapper];
[tapper addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
```

Implement the handler of the tap like:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    UIImageView *imageView = recognizer.view;
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Fork.png"];
}
```

If you need to do something like have it adjust the image when you tap it you'll probably want to try a `UIButton` with the custom type and set the image accordingly. Anyways, hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Carl, the UITapGestureRecognizer was exactly what I was looking for!